# Weird issue with &shy; hanging in browser

Tags: iis, soft-hyphen

I am experiencing an extremely strange problem with IIS 7.5 on Windows Server 2008 R2 64 bit.

Any file (no matter the extension, could be .txt, .htm, .js, or anything) that has an http:// on any line, and a `&shy;` on any subsequent line, cannot be fully downloaded from IIS. You get a partial download that just hangs.

This fails with static content compression on or off, with output caching on or off.

The issue doesn't occur on a local dev environment running IIS 7.5 on Windows 7.

Any thoughts as to the cause?

Comment: How is the download being tested? `curl`? Is there a particular time in the download that the hang occurs? Are there any filters running? Any proxies? Does it [not] work the same if over HTTPS? Any relevant log messages? Does replacing `&shy;` with `&foo;` result in the same behavior? Is the `http://` on the previous line absolutely important in re-creating the behavior? What happens if there is a space after it, as in `http://foobar.com  -- make sure this is not read as a url\n&shy`?

Answer (score 1):

Websense Proxy was the cause.  APparently ­ is used by spammers to disguise their spam, and an overaggressive rule was put in place by our security team.